# 2-D array from txt in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I am needing to create a code that is versatile enough where I can add more columns in the future with minimum reconstruction of my code. My current code does not allow me to travel through my file with my 2-D array. If I was to change MsgBox("map = "+ map(0,1) I can retrieve the value easily. Currently all I get in the code listed is 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' and that Index was outside the bounds of the array. My current text file is 15 rows (down) and 2 columns (across) which puts it at a 14x1. they are also comma separated values.

```
Dim map(14,1) as string 
Dim reader As IO.StreamReader
reader = IO.File.OpenText("C:\LocationOfTextFile")
Dim Linie As String, x,y As Integer
For x = 0 To 14
    Linie = reader.ReadLine.Trim
    For y = 0 To 1 
        map(x,y) = Split(Linie, ",")(y)
    Next 'y
Next 'x
reader.Close()
MsgBox("map = " + map(y,x))``
```

Comment: Think you probably what to read up on the upper bounds of arrays.  Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/) for examples.  That said, probably better mechanics around for csv data than multi-dimensional arrays such has a data table, many 3rd party libraries do all the heavy lifting for you

Comment: You can make it as flexible as you like using a `List(Of List(Of String))`. Then it can have as many lines and/or columns as there are in the file.

Comment: Get thee a dedicated CSV parser.

Comment: In these situations I often read the first line and count the commas to work out how many columns there are.

Comment: What if I wanted to change from a txt file to a csv file? I can not use the same IO.File.OpenText("") what is the difference in a .csv and .txt file with this code?

Answer (score 1):

This is the method suggested by Microsoft. It is generic and will work on any properly formatted comma delimited file. It will also catch and display any errors found in the file.

```
        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                  FileIO.TextFieldParser(
                    "C:\LocationOfTextFile")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dim currentField As String
                For Each currentField In currentRow
                    MsgBox(currentField)
                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
        "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
```

Comment: It works when I have it in between my 2 Next statements. like you said when I use MsgBox("map = " + map(x,0)) this gives me first column then MsgBox("map = " + map(x,1)) this gives me the second column and MsgBox("map = " + map(x,y)) gives me blank results.

Comment: It sounds line your comma delimited file may have some issues. Can you modify your question to show the input file? Other commenters have given excellent suggestions on other ways to read a csv file. You might want to focus on implementing one of them. Either way I will be happy to help.

Comment: I have modified my answer to show a generic way of reading any comma delimited file. It comes from a Microsoft website.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-comma-delimited-text-files

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic way to look at reading the file:

```
Dim data As New List(Of List(Of String))
For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\LocationOfTextFile")
    data.Add(New List(Of String)(line.Split(",")))
Next

Dim row As Integer = 1
Dim col As Integer = 10
Dim value As String = data(row)(col)
```

Comment: This helps but what if  I wanted to change from a txt file to a csv file? I can not use the same IO.File.OpenText("") what is the difference in a .csv and .txt file with this code?

Comment: There is no difference. A `.csv` is literally a `.txt` file with a different extension. You can edit a `.csv` in any text editor. So, yes, you can use the same code with a `.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you are asking is how can I take the contents of comma-separated values and convert this to a 2D array.

The easiest way, which is not necessarily the best way, is to return an IEnuemrable(Of IEnumerable(Of String)). The number of items will grow both vertically based on the number of lines and the number of items will grow horizontally based on the values split on a respective line by a comma.

Something along these lines:

```vb
Private Function GetMap(path As String) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim map = New List(Of IEnumerable(Of String))()
    Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
    For Each line In lines
        Dim row = New List(Of String)()
        Dim values = line.Split(","c)
        row.AddRange(values)
        map.Add(row)
    Next

    Return map
End Function
```

Now when you want to grab a specific cell using the `(row, column)` syntax, you could use:

```vb
Private _map As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of String))
Private Sub LoadMap()
    _map = GetMap("C:/path-to-map")
End Sub

Private Function GetCell(row As Integer, column As Integer) As String
    If (_map Is Nothing) Then
        LoadMap()
    End If

    Return _map.ElementAt(row).ElementAt(column)
End Function
```

Here is an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZmY5Ki

Keep in mind that there are some issues with this, for example:

1. What if you have commas in your cells?
2. What if you try to access a cell that doesn't exist?

These are considerations you need to make when implementing this in more detail.

Comment: How can I view all in one column?

Comment: @NathanielTurner - `_map.ElementAt(row)`

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the `DataTable` class for this. It uses much more memory than an array, but gives you a lot of versatility in adding columns, filtering, etc. You can also access columns by name rather than index.

You can bind to a `DataGridView` for visualizing the data.

It is something like an in-memory database.

Comment: would DataTable read from a .csv easier?

Comment: A [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-7.0) does not read a `.csv`. A DataTable is a construct to store the data and allows you to ask questions of it, for instance using SQL. You still need a separate mechanism to read the `.csv` file, like a [data adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapters-and-datareaders), a stand-alone third-party library, or manually rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

This is much like @Idle_Mind's suggestion, but saves an array copy operation and at least one allocation *per row* by using an array, rather than a list, for the individual rows:

```vb
Dim data = File.ReadLines("C:\LocationOfTextFile").
    Select(Function(ln) ln.Split(","c)).
    ToList()

' Show last row and column:
Dim lastRow As Integer = data.Count - 1
Dim lastCol As Integer = data(row).Length - 1
MsgBox($"map = {data(lastRow)(lastCol)}")
```

Here, assuming `Option Infer`, the `data` variable will be a `List(Of String())`

As a step up from this, you could also define a class with fields corresponding to the expected CSV columns, and map the array elements to the class properties as another call to `.Select()` before calling `.ToList()`.

But what I *really* recommend is getting a dedicated CSV parser from NuGet. While a given CSV source is usually consistent, more broadly the format is known for having a number of edge cases that can easily confound the `Split()` function. Therefore you tend to get better performance and consistency from a dedicated parser, and NuGet has several good options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example showing how to use the first row to decide how many columns your file has. We store the array in `(column, row)` order because `Redim Preserve` only works on the final index of the array (and we are more likely to add rows than columns).

```
Dim filename = "C:\Junk\example.csv"
Dim lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
If lines.Length > 0 Then
  Dim colCount = Split(lines(0), ",").Length
  Dim rowCount = lines.Length
  Dim map(colCount - 1, rowCount - 1)
  For row = 0 To rowCount - 1
    Dim values = Split(lines(row), ",", colCount)
    For col = 0 To colCount - 1
      map(col, row) = values(col)
    Next col
  Next row
  'display results
  For row = 0 To map.GetUpperBound(1)
    For col = 0 To map.GetUpperBound(0)
      Console.Write(map(col, row) + ":")
    Next col
    Console.WriteLine()
  Next row
End If
```